# Create a blank button and name it when is selected Java

Tags: java, swing

[image]

I'm working on a game puzzle with an AI algorithm. 
When the game starts I want all the buttons to be blank, in order that user will set up his board and when he press `solve` button the game will be solved.

The algorithm works and the game is solved when I enter the number in console, but I don't know how to reflect that into GUI.

```
public static int[] getConsoleInput() {

    System.out.println("\nEnter a valid 8-puzzle below:");
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    String t = handleBlankSpaces(scanner.nextLine());
    String m = handleBlankSpaces(scanner.nextLine());
    String b = handleBlankSpaces(scanner.nextLine());

    return convertToArray(String.format("%s %s %s", t, m, b));
  }
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: What is unclear?
"want the user to select a button for example the one that now is "3", and change his name."

Comment: That's not a question.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the setText() method of the button. He you are an example, you could improve it.

```
package asar.analitics.test;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class Calculator extends JFrame{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public Calculator() {

        final JButton btnNewButton = new JButton();
        btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                if(btnNewButton.getText().isEmpty())
                    btnNewButton.setText("Hi");
                else
                    btnNewButton.setText("Bye");

            }
        });
        getContentPane().add(btnNewButton, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Calculator calculator = new Calculator();
        calculator.setSize(400, 400);
        calculator.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

[image]